# Is there any template of test case document for API testing?

Tags: manual-testing, api-testing

I have tried search online about sample test case document for API testing,but didn't get any result
Note: i already know about normal test case template

Answer (score 1):

API Test cases

Refer below URL. It'll useful for you.

https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/integrate/api/test/cases

Comment: It's best to write the detailed answer here and use the link as a reference!